# Bomb Lab Phase 1

Tags: assembly, computer-science

I need some help solving phase 1 of my bomb lab. The following assembly code was given under phase_1 of my objdump file:

```
08048ec1 <phase_1>:
8048ec1:    55                      push   %ebp
8048ec2:    89 e5                   mov    %esp,%ebp
8048ec4:    83 ec 28                sub    $0x28,%esp
8048ec7:    8b 45 08                mov    0x8(%ebp),%eax
8048eca:    89 45 e4                mov    %eax,-0x1c(%ebp)
8048ecd:    65 a1 14 00 00 00       mov    %gs:0x14,%eax
8048ed3:    89 45 f4                mov    %eax,-0xc(%ebp)
8048ed6:    31 c0                   xor    %eax,%eax
8048ed8:    83 ec 04                sub    $0x4,%esp
8048edb:    8d 45 e8                lea    -0x18(%ebp),%eax
8048ede:    50                      push   %eax
8048edf:    68 d7 9b 04 08          push   $0x8049bd7
8048ee4:    ff 75 e4                pushl  -0x1c(%ebp)
8048ee7:    e8 c4 f9 ff ff          call   80488b0 <sscanf@plt>
8048eec:    83 c4 10                add    $0x10,%esp
8048eef:    89 45 ec                mov    %eax,-0x14(%ebp)
8048ef2:    83 7d ec 01             cmpl   $0x1,-0x14(%ebp)
8048ef6:    74 05                   je     8048efd <phase_1+0x3c>
8048ef8:    e8 47 04 00 00          call   8049344 <explode_bomb>
8048efd:    83 ec 0c                sub    $0xc,%esp
8048f00:    6a 06                   push   $0x6
8048f02:    e8 27 00 00 00          call   8048f2e <function2>
8048f07:    83 c4 10                add    $0x10,%esp
8048f0a:    89 45 f0                mov    %eax,-0x10(%ebp)
8048f0d:    8b 45 e8                mov    -0x18(%ebp),%eax
8048f10:    3b 45 f0                cmp    -0x10(%ebp),%eax
8048f13:    74 05                   je     8048f1a <phase_1+0x59>
8048f15:    e8 2a 04 00 00          call   8049344 <explode_bomb>
8048f1a:    90                      nop
8048f1b:    8b 45 f4                mov    -0xc(%ebp),%eax
8048f1e:    65 33 05 14 00 00 00    xor    %gs:0x14,%eax
8048f25:    74 05                   je     8048f2c <phase_1+0x6b>
8048f27:    e8 84 f8 ff ff          call   80487b0 <__stack_chk_fail@plt>
8048f2c:    c9                      leave  
8048f2d:    c3                      ret
```

(I am using the Ubuntu Operating System).

I set necassary break points at phase_1 and explode_bomb and I examined the register values just before the explode_bomb occurs. At the point just before my bomb explodes, the value of the $eax register is my input string.

I am struggling to understand what this code does and in particular:

```
8048eef:    89 45 ec                mov    %eax,-0x14(%ebp)
8048ef2:    83 7d ec 01             cmpl   $0x1,-0x14(%ebp)
8048ef6:    74 05                   je     8048efd <phase_1+0x3c>
```

What I understand is that it is comparing my input string to the value $0x1 and then jumping over explode bomb if they are equal. But what is the value of $0x1?

The method that is called:

```
 080488b0 <sscanf@plt>:
 80488b0:   ff 25 6c c0 04 08       jmp    *0x804c06c
 80488b6:   68 c0 00 00 00          push   $0xc0
 80488bb:   e9 60 fe ff ff          jmp    8048720 <_init+0x24>
```

Thank you in advance for any help :)